# Postgresql finding max transaction_id for each type giving duplicates (when it's not supposed to for PK)

Tags: postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

Question as title; So I have a code as shown below to find the ID with highest amount transacted by type of card

```
SELECT tr.identifier, cc.type, tr.amount as max_amount
FROM credit_cards cc, transactions tr 
WHERE (tr.amount, cc.type) IN (SELECT MAX(tr.amount), cc.type   
                FROM credit_cards cc, transactions tr 
                WHERE cc.number = tr.number
                 GROUP BY cc.type)
GROUP BY tr.identifier, cc.type;
```

When I run the code, I get duplicate transaction_identifier which shouldn't happen since it's the PK of the transactions table; output when I run above code is shown below

```
ID --------Card type--------------- Max amount
2196    "diners-club-carte-blanche" 1000.62
2196        "visa"                  1000.62
11141   "mastercard"                1000.54
2378    "mastercard"                1000.54
```

e.g. 2196 in above exists for diners carte-blanche not visa;
'mastercard' is correct since 2 different IDs can have same max transaction.

However, this code should run because it is possible for 2 *different* id to have the same max amount for each type.

Does anyone know how to prevent the duplicates from occurring?

is this due to the WHERE ... IN clause which matches either the max amount or the card type? (the ones with duplicate is Visa and Diners-Carte-Blanche which both have same max value of 1000.62 so I think that's where they're matching wrong)

Comment: That `SELECT` gives you an error? What is the exact error message?

Comment: it doesn't give an error actually but I get duplicated ID values as per photo; ID being PK should not appear twice (also one of the duplicate ID is matched to a card that is not associated with it)

Comment: Do not use images for textual information. Copy and paste the output to your question as text.  Also I'm not seeing how this is going two work without someway to link the `identifier` in the outer query to that in the sub-select.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver ok removed it and have put in as a separate code block for ease of reference. 
issue being it 'works' in that it's possible for 2 IDs to have same max amount (Mastercard in above e.g.) but for id 2196 above, it cannot appear twice for visa and diners (given 2196 is PK + it's only associated with one type)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL/DR: add `WHERE cc.number = tr.number` to the outer query.

#### Long version

When you query `FROM table_1, table_2` in the outer query and don't connect the tables (via a join or where clause) the result is  a [cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product), meaning EVERY row from table_1 is joined to EVERY row from table_2. This is the same as a `CROSS JOIN`.

So while your inner query has a `where` clause and (correctly) returns the max for each credit card type... your outer query does not, and so all possible combinations of credit card and transaction are being compared to the maximums, not just the valid ones.

For example, if cc has rows three rows (mastercard, visa, amex) and tr has three rows (1,2,3)  selecting "from cc, tr" is resulting in nine rows:

```
mastercard,1
mastercard,2
mastercard,3
visa,1
visa,2
visa,3
amex,1
amex,2
amex,3
```

where what you want is:

```
mastercard,1
visa,3
amex,2
```

Each row in the first table will be repeated for each row in the second. Then the `WHERE (...) IN (...)` restrict *this* set of rows to only those that match a row in the inner query. As you can imagine, this can easily lead to duplicate results. Some of those duplicates are being removed by the outer `GROUP BY`, which should not be necessary once this issue is fixed.

As a general rule, I never use `join [table_1], [table_2]` and prefer to ALWAYS be explicit about doing an inner or outer join (or, in some situations, a cross join) to help avoid this kind of issue and make it clearer to the reader.

```
SELECT tr.identifier, cc.type, tr.amount as max_amount
FROM credit_cards cc INNER JOIN transactions tr ON (cc.number = tr.number)
WHERE (tr.amount, cc.type) IN (
  SELECT MAX(tr.amount), cc.type   
  FROM credit_cards cc 
  INNER JOIN transactions tr ON (cc.number = tr.number)
  GROUP BY cc.type
)
```

NOTE: In the case of a tie, this will give you *every* transaction for each credit card type that is tied for the maximum amount.

Comment: thank you for the in-depth explanation! definitely helped me better understand it